# Pandas DataFrame multiplying columns and creating new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some data that has 11 columns.  I need to multiply columns 1-10 by column 11 and then create 10 new columns with those results.  To do this I am using pandas DataFrame.

Now I understand how to do this for each column individually with a code like this

```
df['newcolumn1'] = df['column1']*df['column11']
df['newcolumn2'] = df['column2']*df['column11']
df['newcolumn3'] = df['column3']*df['column11']
```

I'm assuming I can set up a function and a loop to iterate through the columns and create the new columns.  Is there anyway I can do this by referencing the column index number instead of the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of multiplying individually or explicitly looping, you could use [`multiply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) to generate a DataFrame of your new columns, then [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to join things together. Doing so by column number as you would like to may look like

```
pd.concat([df, 
           (df.iloc[:, :10].multiply(df.iloc[:, -1], axis='rows')
                           .add_prefix('new_'))], 
           axis=1)
```

**Minimal example**

```
>>> df
   column1  column2  column3  column4
0        0        1        2        3
1        4        5        6        7
2        8        9       10       11
3       12       13       14       15

>>> pd.concat([df, 
                (df.iloc[:, :3].multiply(df.iloc[:, -1], axis='rows')
                               .add_prefix('new_')], axis=1))], 
                axis=1)

   column1  column2  column3  column4  new_column1  new_column2  new_column3
0        0        1        2        3            0            3            6
1        4        5        6        7           28           35           42
2        8        9       10       11           88           99          110
3       12       13       14       15          180          195          210
```